# Swift UIAlertController with textField and Switch

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
@IBAction func sendMessageBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "SendAlertBox1".localized(), message: "SendAlertBox2".localized(), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: self.OkHandler)
        let okCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(okCancel)
        alertController.view.addSubview(createSwitch())

        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }

    func emailTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        emailTextField = textField
        emailTextField?.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"
    }

    func OkHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!, sender:UISwitch!){
        print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ")
    }

    func createSwitch () -> UISwitch{
        let switchControl = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 0, 0));
        switchControl.isOn = true
        switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false);
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", for: .valueChanged);
        return switchControl
    }
```

The above code is designed to:

1. create `alertControler` with text field `emailTextField`, buttons (Cancel and Send) and switch (in botton this alert).
2. After clicking the SEND button, display the switch and value from `emailTextField` message

I have the following errors:
- in line:

1. `let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SendAlertBox4".localized(), style: .default, handler: self.OkHandler)`

I have error:

> Cannot convert value of type `(UIAlertAction!, UISwitch!) -> ()` to expected argument type `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?`

2. > `emailTextField = textField` - Cannot assign to property: `emailTextField` is a method
3. > `emailTextField?.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"` - Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type `(UITextField!) -> ()`
4. > `let switchControl = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 0, 0));` - `CGRectMake` is unavailable in Swift

Does anyone know how to fix it?

***UPDATE***

```
@IBAction func sendMessageBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "SendAlertBox1".localized(), message: "SendAlertBox2".localized(), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: {action in
            print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : (sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: (emailTextField) ")
        })
        let okCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "SendAlertBox5".localized(), style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(okCancel)
        alertController.view.addSubview(createSwitch())

        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }

    func emailTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        emailTextField = textField
        emailTextField.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"
    }

    func OkHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!, sender:UISwitch!){
        print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ")
    }

    func createSwitch () -> UISwitch{
        let switchControl = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 0, height: 0));
        switchControl.isOn = true
        switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false);
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", for: .valueChanged);
        return switchControl
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@IBAction func sendMessageBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let emailTextField: (UITextField)->Void? = { txtField in
            //code goes here
            txtField.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "SendAlertBox1".localized(), message: "SendAlertBox2".localized(), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: {action in
            print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ")

        })
        let okCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "SendAlertBox5".localized(), style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(okCancel)
        alertController.view.addSubview(createSwitch())

        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }

    func createSwitch () -> UISwitch{
        let switchControl = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 0, height: 0));
        switchControl.isOn = true
        switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false);
        //switchControl.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", for: .valueChanged);
        return switchControl
    }
```

Comment: post code of `OkHandler`.

Comment: func OkHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!, sender:UISwitch!){
        print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ")
    }

Comment: check answer, you have created func instead of closure.

Answer (score 0):

**You have created a func instead you need to create a closures.**

> 1. You need to create an action handler like below.

```
let actionHandlert: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void?) = { (action) in
        //code here
}
```

and then add it in `UIAlertAction` action handler (you have created action handler of type `'(UIAlertAction!, UISwitch!) -> ()'` which is not valid).

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "SendAlertBox4".localized(), style: .default, handler: actionHandlert)
```

> 2 and 3. You need to create a close type and add it in configuration hauler of alert controller as follow.

```
let emailtxtField: (UITextField)->Void? = { txtField in
      //code goes here          
    txtField.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"
}
alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailtxtField)
```

> 4. CGRectMake is renamed as CGRect(...)

```
    let switchControl = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width:0, height: 0))
```

**EDIT**

Things need to changed...

- `sender` is of `Any` type and it has no property `isOn` so you need to change it from Any to `UISwitch`.

  ```
  @IBAction func sendMessageBtnPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) { ...  }
  ```
- To get alert textfield you can create a property and in configuration handler you can assign textfield to email textfield  property like below...

  ```
  @IBAction func sendMessageBtnPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    var myEmailTextFiled = UITextField()

    let emailTextField: ((UITextField)->Void)? = { txtField in

      txtField.placeholder = "example@icloud.com"
      myEmailTextFiled = txtField
    }

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "SendAlertBox1", message: "SendAlertBox2", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: {action in
      print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(myEmailTextFiled.text!) ")

    })
    let okCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "SendAlertBox5", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(okCancel)
    alertController.view.addSubview(createSwitch())

    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
  }
  ```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: I have this code: https://pastebin.com/4LqNnuXM  - I have problem with compile: unc emailTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        emailTextField = textField - Cannot assign to property: 'emailTextField' is a method
        emailTextField.placeholder = "example@icloud.com" - Value of type '(UITextField!) -> ()' has no member 'placeholder'
    }

Comment: and I need value in this print: print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ") - switch is on(1) or not (0) and emailTextField - value from input

Comment: `emailTextField` and `OkHandler` should be closure not a `func`. you need to make it clouser.

Comment: Ok, i change this  with yours suggestion: https://pastebin.com/drbFYi3G Now in this line: alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emailTextField) - I have error: Cannot convert value of type '(UITextField) -> Void?' to expected argument type '((UITextField) -> Void)?' and in print("Action after click OK , Switch Value : \(sender.isOn) and emailTextField text: \(emailTextField) ") - Value of type 'Any' has no member 'isOn'